# use bash string as jq filter

Tags: bash, filtering, eval, jq

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or why this does not work.

`test.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "Header": {
      "Region": "US",
      "Tenant": "Tenant1",
      "Stage": "testing",
      "ProductType": "old"
    },
    "Body": []
  },
  {
    "Header": {
      "Region": "EU",
      "Tenant": "Tenant2",
      "Stage": "development",
      "ProductType": "new"
    },
    "Body": []
  }
]
```

I want to display the values of the `.Header.Tenant` key. So the simple jq call does its job:

```
$ jq '[.[].Header.Tenant]' test.json
[
  "Tenant1",
  "Tenant2"
]
```

Now I want to assign that jq filter to a bash variable and use it with jq's `--arg` variable.

And I am getting this:

```
$ a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq --arg xx "$a" '[$xx]' test.json
[
  ".[].Header.Tenant"
]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your output is exactly what I'd expect it to be, given your code. What do you mean, "what's wrong"?

Comment: Filters are code. Variables are data. They don't substitute for each other. That's true in almost every language, not just jq. The whole point of passing variables out-of-band from code is so they can't be parsed as code by accident, with the correctness and security issues that implies.

Comment: If you _want_ your variable to be parsed as code, just substitute it into the code instead of using `--arg`.

Comment: My question is - if I have a jq filter which is 500 char long and I need to use it a number of times, do I have to use it 'as is' with every jq call, or is there a way to templating it?

Comment: That sounds like a job for a function. jq _does_ have those.

Comment: You and @peak gave me an idea. The solution is quite simple:
``a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq -f  <(echo "[$a]")   test.json``
Let me expand it and post as an answer.

Comment: Assuming $a is well-enough-behaved: `jq "[$a]" test.json`

Comment: It might not behave well if the filter spans three lines and 400 characters. I think -f is the safer option.

Comment: 400 characters will _easily_ sit in a command-line argument. The combined argv+environment limit on modern systems is over 100kb.

Comment: If your “$a” filter is long or complicated, why put it in a shell variable in the first place? Normally, reusable bits of code are put into files as either programs or modules, or maybe templates.  (See the jq Cookbook for more on jq as a template engine.)

Comment: The script number of API calls. The requirement is that only the result of these API calls in the form of logs should be written into a file or on screen.

Comment: Regarding using ``jq "[$a]" test.json`` - if I for example want to count the length of the array from the ``jq "[$a]" test.json`` output, I have to call jq second times using ``a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq ["$a"]  test.json | jq 'length'``. 

How this is better than my solution using ``a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq -f  <(echo "[$a]|length")   test.json``?

Answer (score 2):

jq does not have an `eval` function for evaluating arbitrary jq expressions, but it does provide functions that can be used to achieve much the same effect, the key idea being that certain JSON values can be used to specify query operations.

In your case, you would have to translate the jq query into a suitable jq operation, such as:

```
jq --argjson a '["Header","Tenant"]' '
   getpath(paths|select( .[- ($a|length) :]== $a))
' test.json
```

### Extending jq's JSON-based query language

More interestingly, you could write your own `eval`, e.g.

```
jq --argjson a '[[], "Header","Tenant"]' '

  def eval($expr):
    if $expr == [] then .
    else $expr[0] as $op
    | if $op == [] then .[] | eval($expr[1:])
      else getpath([$op]) | eval($expr[1:])
      end
    end;
   eval($a)
' test.json
```

### With eval.jq as a module

If the above def of `eval` were put in a file, say ~/jq/eval.jq, then you could simply write:

```
jq -L ~/jq --argjson a '[[], "Header","Tenant"]' '
  include "eval";
  eval($a)' test.json
```

Or you could specify the search path in the jq program:

```
jq --argjson a '[[], "Header","Tenant"]' '
  include "eval" { "search": "~/jq" };
  eval($a)' input.json
```

Or you could use `import` ...

Comment: I do appreciate your wisdom. The very last sentence actually gave me an idea - use ``-f`` and process substitution with ``echo``. It does the job.

Comment: @Invisible999, ...note that `echo` does _most_ jobs badly. `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` is pretty much always preferable to `echo "$foo"`; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo, particularly the notes regarding how even on bash, environment variables can completely reconfigure `echo`'s behavior (for example, making it act like `-e` was passed even when it wasn't; or making `echo -e` print `-e` or output, or various other fun things).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** The following code does the job:

```
$ a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq -f  <(echo "[$a]") test.json
[
  "Tenant1",
  "Tenant2"
]
```

One as well can add/modify the filter in the jq call, if needed:

```
$ a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq -f  <(echo "[$a]|length")   test.json
2
```

**Longer explanation**

My ultimate goal was to figure out how I can define the lowest common denominator jq filter in a variable and use it when calling jq, plus add additional parameters if necessary. If you have a really complex jq filter spanning multiple lines that you call frequently, you probably want to template it somehow and use that template when calling jq.

While *peak* demonstrated how it can be done, I think it is overengineering the simple task.

However, using process substitution combined with the jq's `-f` option to read a filter from the file does solve my problem.

Comment: I'm quite unclear on why one would do this instead of just `jq "[$a]" test.json`, unless you've been abusing the environment and have very little space left for argv contents (both environment variables and command-line arguments use the same pool of memory... but it's not that small of a pool).

Comment: Moreover, `jq --arg "$a" ...` is putting `a` on the argv, so if you didn't have enough space, you would have had a completely different problem with your initial attempt.

Comment: ...if the real situation is that you want to reuse `a` several times over the course of a jq operation, that's what functions are for. `jq "def myfunc(): $a; [myfunc]` and there you are.

Comment: I think you are missing the closing double quote in your example. Also, could you explain what advantages of jq's function would offer compared to my example?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Here is the situation -  I want to count the number of the elements in the array from the ``jq "[$a]" test.json`` output. How do it? My solution ``a=".[].Header.Tenant"; jq -f  <(echo "[$a]|length")`` takes care of it.

I am open to suggestions but want to understand, why my solution is not optimal.